# Solve the recurrence $T(n) = nT(\sqrt{n}) + n^2, T(2) = 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$T(n) = nT(\sqrt{n}) + n^2, T(2) = 1$$

The master theorem does not apply here, only recursion tree. Assume $n = 2^{2^k}$.

The solution for self-check is $T(n = 2^{2^k}) = k \cdot n^2 + \frac{n^2}{4}$.

Edited:

My approach:

$T(2^{2^k}) = 2^{2^k}T(2^{2^{k-1}}) + 2^{2^{k + 1}}$

$= 2^{2^k + 2^{k - 1}}T(2^{2^{k-2}}) + 2^{2^{k+1}} + 2^{2^{k+1}}$

...

$=2^{\sum_{i = 1}^{k} 2^i} + k \cdot 2^{2^{k+1}}$

$=2^{\sum_{i = 0}^{k} 2^i - 1}  + k \cdot 2^{2^{k+1}}$

$=2^{2^{k+1} - 2} + k \cdot n^2$

$=\frac{n^2}{4} + k \cdot n^2$

Comment: for start $2^{2^{k}}\not = 2^{2k} $ and $(2^{2^k} )^2 \not = 2 ^{4k/} $

Comment: @Ahmad thanks that is a good hint

Comment: $n=2^{2^k}\implies n^2=2^{2^{k+1}}\ne 2^{2^k+1}$.

Comment: @user thank you, I edited the post.

Comment: $2^{2^{k+1} - 1}=\frac{n^2}2\ne\frac{n^2}4$.

Comment: @user thanks again. I am now a bit unsure of the final result. Did I make a mistake or is the result for self-checking false?

Comment: Yes you made a mistake: the sum in the exponent should start with $i=1$ not $0$.

Comment: @user thanks a lots, you were so patient to me.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Let first rewrite the equation: $$T(n^2)=n^2T(n)+n^4$$

- First step is to homogenize the formula.

Let set $T(n)=n^2U(n)$, after substitution we get $$U(n^2)=U(n)+1$$

- Then we linearize it.

Let set $n=2^p$ and $V(p)=U(n)$, after substitution we get $$V(2p)=V(p)+1$$

Let set $p=2^q$ and $W(q)=V(p)$, after substitution we get $$W(q+1)=W(q)+1$$

- Solve the formula (notice it is a telescoping sequence)

$$W(q)=W(0)+q$$

- Last step is to go back up the chain of substitutions

$W(0)=V(2^0)=V(1)=U(2^1)=U(2)=\dfrac{T(2)}{2^2}=\dfrac 14$

$q=\log_2(\log_2(n))$

$T(n)=n^2U(n)=n^2V(p)=n^2W(q)=n^2(\frac 14+q)$

> $$T(n)=\frac 14n^2 + n^2\log_2(\log_2(n))$$

Comment: I came to the solution, but still thanks :)